# How to assign command line variables to char in c++

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I want to read a string and parse it in C++ to convert it to char from command line.

example:

```
sample.exe "Username" "Password"
```

I want to assign the `argv[1]`and `argv[2]` to some char value like below,

```
char buffer[MAX_BUF_LEN] = argv[1];
```

Help me on this

Comment: You've tagged the question c++11 so why not just put it in a `std::string` with `std::string buffer{ argv[1] };` and have all the convenience of a `std::string` rather than the hassle of having to learn how to perform safe `strcpy`s and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    assert(argc >= 3);
    std::string user(argv[1]);
    std::string pass(argv[2]);
}
```